# how to pipeline HTTPoison.Response.body

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to write simple app using Elixir language. `HTTPoison.get!` returns `HTTPoison.Response` structure with `body` key. Is it possible to include this logic to pipeline?

```
Repo.one(Site).sitemap_url 
|> HTTPoison.get! 
|> ...
|> Floki.find("sitemap loc") 
|> Enum.map(fn(element) -> Floki.text(element) end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#structs-are-bare-maps-underneath), structs are just maps. Hence, you can use the functions from the `Map` module, including `Map.get` to extract keys:

```
Repo.one(Site).sitemap_url 
|> HTTPoison.get! 
|> Map.get(:body)
|> Floki.find("sitemap loc") 
|> Enum.map(fn(element) -> Floki.text(element) end)
```